# Netbeans 8.1 muestra el splash y se muere

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, netbeans-8.1

Intenté bajar el netbeans desde la tienda de aplicaciones de Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS y bajó sin problemas, pero la tratar de abrirlo se moría bien feo y en el archivo de logs que genera que aparece en `/home/NOMBREDEUSUARIO/.netbeans/8.1/var/log` se podía ver el mensaje de error

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)

Busqué en el stackoverflow gringo pero me salió que era por tener Java 9 cosa que no aplica ya que tengo el OpenJDK 1.8.0_191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Solucionado! Resulta que gracias a un [reporte de error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/1776937) lo pude solucionar.

EL procedimiento es descargar una versión anterior de la librería `libequinox-osgi-java_3.8.1-10`.

Yo la hallé en esta liga: https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/libequinox-osgi-java_3.8.1-10_all.deb.html

Tras instalarla mediante doble click para remplazar la versión más actual que tenía abrió sin problemas.